# how can i set mysql connection charactor in sqlapi++

Tags: mysql

I want to use mysql with utf8, but i dont know how to set this.

can anyone help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply perform this query:

```
command.setCommandText("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
command.Execute();
```